# How to select one image from div and get id value

Tags: jquery, html

I have some code, I want to get id value from one of image list.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('preview').on('click', '.preview', function() {
    var imgVal = $(this).attr('id');

    alert(imgVal)


  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/fce/fff.png" id="0" class="img-fluid w-25" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/dce/fff.png" id="1" class="img-fluid w-25" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/acb/fff.png" id="2" class="img-fluid w-25" />
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/abc/fff.png" id="3" class="img-fluid w-25" />

</div>
```

How to get the ID? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be img in the div onclick not div onclick.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.preview img').on('click', function () {
       console.log($(this).attr("id"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="preview">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/fce/fff.png" id="0" class="img-fluid w-25" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/dce/fff.png" id="1" class="img-fluid w-25" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/acb/fff.png" id="2" class="img-fluid w-25" />
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300/abc/fff.png" id="3" class="img-fluid w-25" />

</div>
```

Comment: How to get the current id from clicked image? not all image id